# extending api.html per viewset django rest framework: template inheritance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to provide a template name to a viewset in DRF, such that this new template extends api.html?

new_template.html

```
{% extends 'api.html' %}

{% block my-new-block %}
 TEST
{% endblock %}
```

I can't see how to do it currently, and setting 'template_name' hasn't had any effect. I need to display content differently depending on the particular endpoint.

EDIT: Tried overwriting the retrieve method and adding 'rest_framework.renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer', to the DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES in settings.py.

```
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
    return Response(serializer.data, template_name='new_template.html')
```

However, this seems to have zero effect.

Comment: So you're already doing this in your api.html
`{% extends "rest_framework/base.html" %}` but now you have a `new_template.html` which per your info is `{% extends 'api.html' %}`?

what is your browser saying?  I'm guessing `TEST` does not show in the source at all?

Comment: I'm not seeing TEST in the browser, no :(

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to subclass renderers.BaseRenderer and set your own template. In the view, you can set the renderer_classes attribute to your own custom renderer